# Get the max value of different sum values in sql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a table called "Sold_tickets" with attributes "Ticket_id" and "Date_sold". I want to find the day when the most tickets have been sold and the amount of tickets that were sold.

```
ticket_id   date_sold
1           2017-02-15
2           2017-02-15
3           2017-02-14
```

In this case I want my output to look like this:

```
date_sold   amount
2017-02-15  2
```

I know you can use a query like this

```
SELECT Count(ticket_id) 
FROM Sold_tickets 
WHERE date_sold = '2017-02-15';
```

to get an output of 2. The same can of course be done for 2017-02-14 to get an output of 1. However, then I have to manually check all the dates and compare them myself. Does a function exist (in sqlite) that counts the tickets sold for all the dates and then shows you only the maximum value?

Comment: So you'd like the count for each date, but only see it for the date with the maximum count?

Comment: Well I thought it was necessary to have the count for each date in order to compare them. But yes, I only want the date with the maximum count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `GROUP BY` aggregation query, then retain only the record having the maximum number of sales.

```
SELECT date_sold, COUNT(*)
FROM Sold_tickets 
GROUP BY date_sold
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This solution would work well assuming that you don't have two or more dates tied for the greatest number of sales, or, if there is a tie, that you don't mind choosing just one date group.

Comment: It appears Robbebeest is happy with getting the day with the least number of tickets …

Comment: Thank you Tim.
CL: I added a DESC after ORDER BY count(*) which resulted in the day with the most number of tickets.